# Python | use a printed value before

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

i'm actually trying to dev a slack bot with python. I'm learning python and slack api at the same time and i want to know how can i use a value printed before ?

```
   import os 
from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter 
from slack import WebClient
from slack.errors import SlackApiError
import time

client = WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_KEY'])

response = client.chat_postMessage(
    channel='starterbot',
    text="Hello, are you there ?")
assert response["message"]["text"] == "Hello, are you there ?"


RTM_READ_DELAY = 2
time.sleep(RTM_READ_DELAY)

print(response['ts'])


# if response == "Yes":
    
# elif response != "Yes":
#   client.chat_postMessage(
#       channel='starterbot',
#       text="Bye!")

if client.conversations_replies(channel='C01665VJ2JH', ts='1593523175.013300') == "Yes":
    client.chat_postMessage(channel='starterbot', text="u sure ?")
```

i want to create a variable to save the ts value that i print, and then use it in the client.conversations_replies.

Ty for your help

Comment: posted or printed ?

Comment: please, clarify your question?

Comment: Am I right that `print(response['ts'])` and `if client.conversations_replies(...` lines are actually in the different functions? And you want to save `response['ts']` in the first function to use it later in the `client.conversations_replies(...` function? If yes please update your answer so it contain this function structure.

Comment: @SergeyShubin you are right. i want to use  response['ts'] later. but i don't know how to do.  to do this i have to save the value in a variable but idk how

Comment: @m-zayan what's the difference ?

Comment: In case of `print` ---> (`stdout` python) then you just cache the results, in case of post caching results it's a memory consuming so you could use search instead,moreover caching does not serve runtime bot user (`RTM`), except you are using database.

Comment: @LahayeLucas I mean you can write `ts = response['ts']` and then use `ts` variable in the `if client.conversations_replies(...` condition. But it looks like there is some problem with it, isn't it? What is it?

Comment: @SergeyShubin for your help, it works. i have just write ts = response['ts'] and then use ts variable. But i have another question. I want to know how can i detect and answer to a user with the api. i've found chat.postmessage to post message but i didnt found chat.getmessage of something like that. can u help me ?

Comment: @m-zayan ty for your help too

Comment: @LahayeLucas It will be better to write new question for it to help another SO users find it. Try to provide [mre] in your new question. Good luck!